# InkCanvas and ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

InkCanvas stores all the drawing etc in "Strokes" collection and stores all the controls in "Children".

When I draw something then create a TextBox the TextBox remains under the drawing. I can't change its zIndex to bring it forward.

Is there a way to bring the text on top?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InkCanvas is not really meant for content other than strokes. But you could add the TextBox to another Panel that is over the InkCanvas, e.g.:

```
<Grid>
    <InkCanvas/>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBox/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```